# Shiro Security with Spring Web flow

Tags: spring-webflow, shiro

Can we secure Spring web flow with Shiro security? Please let me know if we can do it. In Spring Web Flow documentation I could find out that Spring web flow can be secured through Spring Security "secured" element. Need to know if it is possible with Shiro Security?

Thanks,
Taj

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses Shiro Security. See "Communities Using Shiro" on http://shiro.apache.org/

And here is a guide how to [Integrate Apache Shiro into Spring based Applications](http://shiro.apache.org/spring.html)